# Is it possible to add an option to the Arrange Icons menu?

Tags: c#, sorting, desktop

I have written a short console based C# application which automatically arranges my desktop icons.

Is it possible to add an entry into the desktop "Arrange Icons By" menu for my custom sorting?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.extremetech.com/article2/0,1697,1839078,00.asp) might show you enough technique to get started.

Comment: Ideally I would like to do this programmatically. 

I found this (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/appendmenu.aspx) example that works almost the way I want, except I am not sure which registry entry I would need to change to add directly to the sort menu.